# Connect to AWS S3 bucket from pods running in GKE cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, amazon-iam

I have workloads running in my GKE cluster and i want one of the workload to connect to AWS S3 private bucket, how can we achieve it?

Comment: Have you tried to use the AWS S3 SDK in your workload to access the bucket?

Comment: I am asking about the authenitcation , what shall be the approach to authenitcate like through WI OIDC token or through Access Keys , please correct me if i am missing something

Comment: It's unclear from your question what you want to achieve. From what I can gather, an AWS IAM account with programmatic access and access keys is the most straightforward way to access an S3 bucket.

Comment: So , you are suggesting to mount secret with access keys on gke cluster to access s3 bucket ?

Comment: Have a look at this [link](https://lingxiankong.github.io/2022-02-13-access-resource-multi-clouds.html)

Comment: Workload Identity only works inside GCP. Workload Identity Federation works from other Cloud providers (AWS, Azure...) to GCP.

What you need to authenticate from a workload running inside GCP toward AWS. for that the only way is AWS Secrets and Access Keys. You can manage them like you would manage a secret. Have a look at this article which highlits options for secret management on GKE https://medium.com/google-cloud/consuming-google-secret-manager-secrets-in-gke-911523207a79